# Unable to get email of facebook user

Tags: php

I am unable to get the email of the Facebook user. Here is the code. How can i get the email address of the user, please help.

```
    if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
        $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              // To Get Facebook ID
        $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name'); // To Get Facebook full name
        $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');    // To Get Facebook email ID
    /* ---- Session Variables -----*/
        $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;           
        $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
        $_SESSION['email'] =  $femail;
        $args = array('scope' => 'email');
        $_SESSION["args"] = $args;
    /* ---- header location after session ----*/
  header("Location: ../");
} else {
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
 header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
}
?>
```

Comment: Facebook isn't going to give you the email address of a user.

Comment: ^not without permissions, no.

Comment: @Marcus then how can i set permisions ... ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

Answer (score 0):

Simply by using the following as your API request:

```
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me?fields=id,name,email' );
  $response = $request->execute();
```

I hope this answered your question!

Comment: I did this it it returned me the email
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'email'));

Answer (score 0):

this thing helped me and i got the result :)

```
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'email'));
```